# Error in AutoText when type a word and generate url is not valid

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, android-volley, android-googleapiclient

Here is my code for review I am not able to resolve this error. My generated value is append with hexadecimal number, normal , null ....

[Map Api Url](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=a&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAJKpL6YNyhf_bhoZMk5exe2lJc8Sm7L6M) 0x22cd051c NORMAL null

[Here is image of exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEUS7.png) :

```
GetDirectionActivity.java
public class GetDirectionActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher,
        Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener {
    String url;
    private static final String TAG_RESULT = "predictions";
    JSONObject json;

    AutoCompleteTextView actvGDOrigin;
    ArrayList<String> names;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String browserKey = "AIzaSyAJKpL6YNyhf_bhoZMk5exe2lJc8Sm7L6M";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_direction);
        actvGDOrigin = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvGDOrigin);
        actvGDOrigin.setThreshold(3);
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        actvGDOrigin.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    public void updateList(String place) {
        String input = "";

        try {
            input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place, "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String output = "json";
        String parameter = input + "&sensor=false&key="
                + browserKey;

        url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"
                + output + "?" + parameter;
        Log.d("url", url);

        DataRequest dataRequest = new DataRequest(Method.GET, url, null, this, this);
         Log.d("datarequest:",dataRequest.toString());
        RouteViaApp.getInstance().addToReqQueue(dataRequest, "jreq");
    }

    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        try {

            JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                String description = c.getString("description");
                Log.d("description", description);
                names.add(description);
            }

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names) {
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    TextView text = (TextView) view
                            .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    return view;
                }
            };
            actvGDOrigin.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (s.toString().length() <= 3) {
            names = new ArrayList<String>();
            updateList(s.toString());
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

RouteViaApp.java
public class RouteViaApp extends Application {
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static RouteViaApp mInstance;
    public static final String TAG = RouteViaApp.class
            .getSimpleName();
    @Override   
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }
    public static synchronized RouteViaApp getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }
    public RequestQueue getReqQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }
    public <T> void addToReqQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getReqQueue().add(req);
    }
    public <T> void addToReqQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getReqQueue().add(req);
    }
    public void cancelPendingReq(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    } 
}
CustomJSONObjectRequest.java
public class CustomJSONObjectRequest extends JsonObjectRequest {

    public CustomJSONObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
                                   Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener,
                                   Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return headers;
    }

    @Override
    public RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy() {
        // here you can write a custom retry policy
        return super.getRetryPolicy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It says that *"The provided API key is expired"*, check your google service API Key from here: https://console.developers.google.com/project/robotic-center-92615/apiui/apis/library

Better yet, generate a new key using this documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

It says that "The provided API key is expired".Regenerate your google brower key and make sure that you have enabled Google place api in google developer console.

Comment: is it worked if so please accept answer so that it can be used by others